# Auto populate the data in a jquery slider from a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an announcement list in a page and I have added a `jquery slider` with hard coded data like image and some text.

The slider shows **an image** and **text which has title and body**. My requirement is that I want the slider to take data from the announcement list (Title, body, and image are columns in announcement list).

So the slider text should come from the title and body column and image should come from the image column of announcement list.

What would be the simplest way to do this? It would be best if it can be done using  `javascript` code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to query the list using REST api and getting the items. Instead of using jQuery, I'd suggest using content search to show the slider. There is an OOB slideshow display template which you can customize as per your need.